# How to avoid NAN value in CTC training?

Tags: tensorflow, theano

I want to bulid a CNN+LSTM+CTC model by tensorflow ,but I always get NAN value during training ,how to avoid that?Dose INPUT need to be handle specially？
on the other hand I found that LOSS value is kept around 30 and never decrease any more,Is this condition normal?(I have used theano to written this model before and face the same question) Thanks for any help!

```
 #incoding:utf-8
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
import Get_Data
import random
import time

#load data
model_data_path = "checkpoints.data"
images_path = "/home/liuyi/test/images"
#images_path = "/home/night/test/images"
ans_name = "answer"
images_data, ans_data = Get_Data.get_data(images_path, ans_name)
np.save("/home/liuyi/test/tf_images.npy", images_data)
np.save("/home/liuyi/test/tf_labels.npy", ans_data)
print images_data.shape
print ans_data
#bulid model
#----define----
def conv2d(x, w, b, strides=1):
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, (1, strides, strides, 1), "SAME")
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def dropout(x, rate):
    return tf.nn.dropout(x, rate)

def maxpool2d(x, poolsize=(2,2)):
    px = poolsize[0]
    py = poolsize[1]
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=(1, px, py, 1), strides=(1, px, py, 1),padding="SAME")

def flatten(x):
    return tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)

def full_con(x, w, b):
    x = tf.matmul(x, w)
    return tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)

def LSTM(x, n_input, hidden_units, out_dim, forget_bias = 1.0, layer_num = 1):
    lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_units, forget_bias=forget_bias, state_is_tuple=True,num_proj=out_dim)
    lstms = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm]*layer_num ,state_is_tuple=True)
    x = tf.reshape(x, (int(x.get_shape()[0]), int(x.get_shape()[1]), n_input))
    out, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstms, x, dtype="float")
    out = tf.transpose(out, [1, 0, 2])
    return out
#----define weight----
weights = {
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 8])),
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 8, 16])),
    'wc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 16, 16])),
    'wc4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 16, 16])),
    'wc5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 16, 16])),
    'wc6': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 16, 16])),
    'wf1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3200, 1000])),
    'wf2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1000, 50])),
}
biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([8])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
    'bc3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
    'bc4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
    'bc5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
    'bc6': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16])),
    'bf1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1000])),
    'bf2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([50])),
}
#----define model----
batch_size = 200
num_classes = 26+1+1
max_len = 21
sequence_length = np.full((batch_size),max_len,dtype=np.int32)#!
x = tf.placeholder("float", [batch_size, 200, 60, 1], "images")
y_i = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, 2], "y_i")
y_v = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,], "y_v")
y_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [2,], "y_shape")
#--------CNN Layer--------
conv2do1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
conv2do2 = conv2d(conv2do1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
conv2do2 = maxpool2d(conv2do2)
#--------CNN Layer--------
conv2do3 = conv2d(conv2do2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
conv2do4 = conv2d(conv2do3, weights['wc4'], biases['bc4'])
conv2do4 = maxpool2d(conv2do4)
#--------CNN Layer--------
conv2do5 = conv2d(conv2do4, weights['wc5'], biases['bc5'])
conv2do6 = conv2d(conv2do5, weights['wc6'], biases['bc6'])
conv2do6 = maxpool2d(conv2do6)
#--------Flatten Layer--------
conv2do6 = flatten(conv2do6)
#--------Full Connection--------
fc1 = full_con(conv2do6, weights['wf1'], biases['bf1'])
fc2 = full_con(fc1, weights['wf2'], biases['bf2'])
#--------LSTM Layer--------
lstms = LSTM(fc2, n_input=1, hidden_units=32, out_dim=num_classes, layer_num=3)
#--------CTC Layer--------
ctc_o = tf.nn.ctc_loss(lstms, tf.SparseTensor(y_i, y_v, y_shape), sequence_length)
#----------------
loss = tf.reduce_mean(ctc_o)
ctc_p = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(lstms, sequence_length)[0][0]
o = ctc_p
train = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
#run model
epoch = 200
images_sum = 10000
train_rate = 0.8
slice_pos = 9800

train_images = images_data[:slice_pos]
train_labels = ans_data[:slice_pos]

test_images = images_data[slice_pos:]
test_labels = ans_data[slice_pos:]

random_list = np.arange(slice_pos)

batch_sum = int(slice_pos/batch_size)
test_batch = int(images_sum-slice_pos)/batch_size

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init)
file_name = "out"
for e in range(epoch):
    random.shuffle(random_list)
    for i in range(batch_sum):
        begin_time = time.clock()
        train_x = [train_images[m] for m in random_list[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]]
        train_y = [train_labels[m] for m in random_list[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]]
        train_yi, train_yv, train_ys = Get_Data.SparseDataFrom(train_y)
        batch_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_i: train_yi, y_v: train_yv, y_shape: train_ys})
        sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_i: train_yi, y_v: train_yv, y_shape: train_ys})
        end_time = time.clock()
        print "epoch{0}/{1}: batch{2}/{3} loss={4} time={5}s".format(e+1, epoch, (i+1)*batch_size, slice_pos, batch_loss,(end_time-begin_time)*(batch_sum-i))
    right_num = 0
    loss_sum = 0
    begin_time = time.clock()
    for i in range(test_batch):
        test_x = [test_images[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]]
        test_y = [test_labels[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]]
        test_yi, test_yv, test_ys = Get_Data.SparseDataFrom(test_y)
        tmp_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: test_x, y_i: test_yi, y_v: test_yv, y_shape: test_ys})
        test_ans = sess.run(o, feed_dict={x: test_x, y_i: test_yi, y_v: test_yv, y_shape: test_ys})
        test_ans = Get_Data.SparseDatatoDense(test_ans)
        tmp_right_num = Get_Data.data_difference(test_ans, test_y)
        loss_sum += tmp_loss
        right_num += tmp_right_num
    end_time = time.clock()
    print "epoch{0}/{1}: loss={2} right_num = {3} time={4}s".format(e + 1, epoch, loss_sum, right_num, end_time - begin_time)
    saver.save(sess, model_data_path)
sess.close()
```

Comment: Nan values usually produced by operations such as log of zero or dividing by number very close to zero. Consider posting your code for more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might have already solved this given how old the question is but...

Using the Torch bindings for warp-ctc I was also generating `nans` until I added an extra output dimension for the `BLANK` label.

Try `out_dim=num_classes+1` in your LSTM.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Also, make sure your sequence length that you input into the CTC loss function reflects the true output size adjusted for the effects of convolution, it's important for masking out the padding in your minibatch tensor and you'll get invalid results .